# ViewPager stops displaying Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have an android application that employs a viewpager.
The viewpager displays two fragments.
I have a portrait and landscape version of the activity that contains the viewpager.
The problem i have is that the viewpager only displays its contents the first time either the portrait or landscape screen is displayed.
The sequence of events are...
**a).Display portrait screen OK

b). switch orientation and landscape displays OK

c). switch back to portrait and the viewpager is blank**

the same result occurs when i start in landscape mode and switch to portrait and back again.

my pageadapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter.

each time my Activity onCreate is called i create the fragments and add them to asd follows:-

```
final List fragments = getFragments(result);
mPageAdapter = new MyPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.guess_view_pager);
mViewPager.setAdapter(mPageAdapter);
```

**My page adapter looks like this**

```
private class MyPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private List fragments;
public MyPageAdapter(final FragmentManager fm, final List fragments) {
super(fm);
this.fragments = fragments;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(final int position) {
return this.fragments.get(position);
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
return this.fragments.size();
}
}
```

another "odd" thing is that my screen has a toggle button. once i get to the point where the viewpager is blank, e.g. switched between portrait, landscape, back to portrait, if i click on the togglebutton the viewpager displays correctly.
do i need to call `invalidate()` or something on my viewpager?

Comment: hye, did y0u try my solution.? i also had that problem of data disappearing , got it fixed with what i mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line on your AndroidManifest.xml (inside activity declaration which is handling the viewpager).

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```